# Mode in point coordinate data set

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a set of point coordinates(x,y) stored in a vector. I would like to find the mode (the most common point) in the vector. I found many algorithms how to calculate mode but how do you find the mode in a point coordinates data set?

```
typedef struct Points{
    int x;
    int y;
}Point

vector<Points> myPoint;
```

Example, myPoint: (0,0), (2,3), (6,2), (2,3), (4,1), ...
Mode is (2,3),

```
Points currpoint = myPoint[0]; 
int counter = 1;
int maxcounter = 1;
Points mode = myPoint[0];

int n = myPoints.size();
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    if ( myPoint[i] == currpoint  )  // !!! "==" produces error
        ++counter;
    else {                              // next point started...
       if (counter > maxcounter) { // new mode candidate
           maxcounter = counter;
           mode = currvalue;
       }
       currpoint = myPoint[i]; // ready to count next point
       counter = 1;
     }
}
cout << "Mode: " << mode << endl;
```

The "==" operand produces error, am I doing the right way by comparing the structure "Points"?

**[Corrected]**

```
Points currpoint = myPoint[0]; 
int counter = 1;
int maxcounter = 1;
Points mode = myPoint[0];

int n = myPoints.size();
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    if ( myPoint[i].x == currpoint.x && myPoint[i].y == currpoint.y )  
        ++counter;
    else {                              
       if (counter > maxcounter) { 
           maxcounter = counter;
           mode = currvalue;
       }
       currpoint = myPoint[i]; 
       counter = 1;
     }
}

if (counter > maxcounter) { 
    maxcounter = counter;
    mode = currvalue;
 }

cout << "Mode: " << mode.x <<", "<< mode.y << endl;
```

Comment: Use one of the many algorithms you found?

Comment: What is the mode of (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)?

Comment: All points occurs equally(once) so there's no mode in the above data set.

Comment: appreciate if you can point me in the right direction

Comment: Count the number of occurrences of each point, return the max if it is unique, otherwise thrown an exception that the mode doesn't exist?

Comment: It works when I count and compare numbers but not points struct. The "myPoint[i] == currpoint" produces an error....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the error because `==` is not overloaded by `struct Points`.

Two solutions:

1. Overload `==` operator for `struct Points`:

   ```
   typedef struct Points{
       int x;
       int y;

       bool operator==(const Points& a) const
       {
           return (x == a.x && y == a.y);
       }
   }Point;
   ```
2. Replace

   ```
   if ( myPoint[i] == currpoint )
   ```

   to

   ```
   if ( myPoint[i].x==currpoint.x && myPoint[i].y==currpoint.y)
   ```